# Why does this code print [2,3,4,5] instead of the full set?

Tags: python, list

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b  = a
a.remove(a[0])
print(b)
```

The values of `a` have been stored into `b` before `a.remove` was called. I don't get how this works.

Comment: `b = a` This does NOT make a copy of `a`.

Answer (score 2):

because the `b` list is just a reference to `a` list and not a copy by value. if you want to have a copy of `a` list, try this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = a[:]
a.remove(a[0])
print(b)
```